# Area of integral with $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: integration

Area of $f'(x)$ knowing that $f(x)=x^{2} \, e^{-x^2}$. I tried calculating $$\int_{-2}^{1} f'(x) \, dx$$  which is actually $f(x)$ from $-2$ to $1$ but it doesn't give me the correct answer.

Comment: You have the right approach but you're using your calculator incorrectly

Comment: What answer did you get?

Comment: $$\int_{-2}^1 f'(x)\,dx=f(1)-f(-2)=e^{-1}-4e^{-4}$$

Comment: How can we find your error if we don't see your work?

Comment: I got 1/e-1/e^4

Comment: Im having dificulties understanding areas with integrals,I thought maybe I need to split the integral

Comment: Signed or unsigned area? Notice that $f’$ changes its sign at $0$.

Comment: "How can we find your error if we don't see your work?" This is not the first time you have been explained this, is it?

Comment: A function, or an integral, does not have an *area*.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

For $a>b$, and given a function $f$ which has a first derivative continuous over the interval $(a,b)$, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus provides
$$
 \int_{b}^{a} f'(x) dx = f(a) - f(b)
$$

In this example
$$
 f(x) = x^{2} e^{-x^{2}}
$$
so
$$
 \int_{-2}^{1} f'(x) dx = f(1) - f(-2) = \frac{1}{e}-\frac{4}{e^4}
$$

The function is plotted below:
[image: plot]

Comment: $f’$ changes its sign and usually area means unsigned area.

Comment: @user251257: The integral "washes away" the derivative, leaving the original function.

Comment: The point is whether “area” below the $x$ axis is negative or not. That is, are we talking about signed or unsigned area. If you need an example, what is the area between $sin(x)$ and the $x$ axis from $x=0$ to $x=2\pi$?